# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Message

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, jar

I am trying to send email using Javax in the spark env. When I try to build this code in IntelliJ it is building properly without any issues.

But when I bring this code to the server and try to run it I am getting the below error

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Message**

**Scala Code Snippet**

```
    val message = new MimeMessage(session)
    message.setFrom("abc@xyz.com")
    //message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to_address)
    message.addRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, "abc@xyz.com")
```

I have tried by keeping **javax.mail-1.5.6.jar** as well as  **commons-email-1.5.jar** in my class path in the server and still getting this error.

**Spark Commands**

```
spark-submit --master yarn --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0 --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/home/abc/commons-email-1.5.jar,/home/abc/activation-1.1.1.jar --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/abc/commons-email-1.5.jar,/home/abc/activation-1.1.1.jar --jars /home/abc/commons-email-1.5.jar --jars /home/abc/activation-1.1.1.jar --class com.abc.common.utils.UtilityMailer ./abc-xyz.jar
```

```
spark-submit --master yarn --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0 --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/home/abc/javax.mail-1.5.6.jar,/home/abc/activation-1.1.1.jar --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/abc/javax.mail-1.5.6.jar,/home/abc/activation-1.1.1.jar --jars /home/abc/javax.mail-1.5.6.jar --jars /home/abc/activation-1.1.1.jar --class com.abc.common.utils.UtilityMailer ./abc-xyz.jar
```

Kindly Help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take a guess… You are experiencing a clash of package names because:

- You are developing in a Java EE environment, and
- You are deploying to a Jakarta EE environment.

Java EE uses `javax.*` package naming. After Oracle Corp handed responsibility for Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation, they changed the package naming to `jakarta.*`.

You can read more about this Jakarta transition in *many* places in the industry press, video lectures, and conference presentations.

To fix your problem, either:

- Downgrade your deployment environment to Java EE, or
- Upgrade your development environment to Jakarta EE. This includes changing your `import` statements from `javax` to `jakarta`.

Both choices are valid. Most vendors will support their Java EE era products for years. But future improvements and innovations will happen mainly in the new generation of Jakarta EE product releases. So you’ll eventually want to migrate to Jakarta EE. But doing so is not urgent.